# How to summarize child group by parent group summation using dplyr in r

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I have generated data as follows:

```
Group  Detail  Value  Count  Count_Avg
A      P       1.25   2      0.63  
A      K       0.5    1      0.50  
A      Y       0.25   1      0.25
B      D       0.75   2      0.38
B      G       33.5   18     1.86
B      Q       17.5   18     0.97
```

The full set of  *data* for the code below has for example: 2 instances of Detail "P" in Group "A" with a sum of a variable called Time (not shown, Time for P1 = 0.75, Time for P2 = 0.50) of 1.25 for the Value and an average of 0.63 for the Count_Avg. There are 18 instances of Detail "G" in Group "B" with a sum of 33.5 for the Value and an average of 1.86 for the Count_Avg, and so on.

This is the code that I use to generate the above table.

```
data %>%
group_by(Group,
         Detail) %>%
summarise(Value = sum(Time),
          n = n(),
          Count_Avg = Value/n)
```

I want to add another column that is the percentage of *Group* for each *Detail*. As an example:

Total Value for all Details in Group "A" = 1.25 + 0.5 + 0.25 = 2.0, 
and the percentage of Detail "P" in Group "A"= 1.25/2.0 = 0.625. The resultant table would look like this:

```
Group  Detail  Value  Count  Count_Avg  Detail_Pcnt
A      P       1.25   2      0.63       0.625
A      K       0.5    1      0.50       0.250
A      Y       0.25   1      0.25       0.125
B      D       0.75   1      0.75       0.014
B      G       33.5   18     1.86       0.647
B      Q       17.5   18     0.97       0.338
```

Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: Your code doesn't at all link up with your data

Comment: I already fixed your formatting, I'm going to roll back your changes back, OK?

Comment: My guess is that you want to add `%>% mutate(perc = Value / sum(Value))` to the end of your pipe chain.

Comment: Many thanks Axman, both fixing the formatting (which I also did), but more importantly the answer; that worked perfectly. It is always the obvious that is the most difficult to see.

Comment: @cuttlefish44, `mutate` by itself already respects grouping in calculating the `sum`, and should be faster than using `do`.